# extract values from JSON using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{
    "Accounts": [
        {
            "Id": "1",
            "Name": "Joe",
            "Zip": "11111"
        },
        {
            "Id": "2",
            "Name": "Jack",
            "Zip": "22222"
        }
    ]   
}
```

I am trying to write a `jq` query that gives me this:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "Name": "Joe"
    },
    {
        "Id": "2",
        "Name": "Jack"
    }   
]
```

How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: One way to show research effort (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) is to show what you've tried.

Comment: Have you tried using any JQ constructs? Use jqterm.com to test using different JQ constructs.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

```
jq '.Accounts | map({ Id, Name })'
```

Will produce

```json
[
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "Name": "Joe"
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "Name": "Jack"
  }
]
```

as you can try online using [this demo](https://jqplay.org/s/t6QAdSoS35).

---

- `.Accounts` selects the `Accounts` key
- `map()` will apply the following for each object <sup>[[docs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example21)]</sup>
- Create object with `Id` and `Name` key <sup>[[docs]](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example11)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Demo https://jqplay.org/s/v01P2gDVc8

You can do

```
[.Accounts[] | {Id, Name}]
```